# Finding minimum moves required for making 2 strings equal

Tags: string, algorithm

This is a question from one of the online coding challenge (which has completed).
I just need some logic for this as to how to approach.

**Problem Statement:**
We have two strings A and B with the same super set of characters. We need to change these strings to obtain two equal strings. In each move we can perform one of the following operations:

```
1. swap two consecutive characters of a string  
2. swap the first and the last characters of a string
```

A move can be performed on either string.
What is the **minimum** number of moves that we need in order to obtain two equal strings?

**Input Format and Constraints:**
The first and the second line of the input contains two strings A and B. It is guaranteed that the superset their characters are equal.

```
1 <= length(A) = length(B) <= 2000
All the input characters are between 'a' and 'z'
```

**Output Format:**
Print the **minimum** number of moves to the only line of the output

```
Sample input:
aab
baa

Sample output:
1
```

**Explanation:**
Swap the first and last character of the string aab to convert it to baa. The two strings are now equal.

**EDIT :** Here is my first try, but I'm getting wrong output. Can someone guide me what is wrong in my approach.

```c
int minStringMoves(char* a, char* b) {
    int length, pos, i, j, moves=0;
    char *ptr;
    length = strlen(a);

    for(i=0;i<length;i++) {
        // Find the first occurrence of b[i] in a
        ptr = strchr(a,b[i]);
        pos = ptr - a;

        // If its the last element, swap with the first
        if(i==0 && pos == length-1) {
            swap(&a[0], &a[length-1]);
            moves++;
        }
        // Else swap from current index till pos
        else {
            for(j=pos;j>i;j--) {
                swap(&a[j],&a[j-1]);
                moves++;
            }
        }

        // If equal, break
        if(strcmp(a,b) == 0)
            break;       
   }

   return moves;
}
```

Comment: "This is a question from ..." - a link always helps, if possible.

Comment: What are your ideas on this problem? What have you tried so far? Have you considered some Greedy or Dynamic Programming approach?

Comment: Probably a specific version of finding the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) problem.

Comment: Typically those coding challenge sites post the answers after the challenge has completed. Have you checked there?

Comment: @jambono if you read the question he's not asking for a solution, he's asking for help with an approach.

Comment: Just read the Dynamic Programming chapter from Cormen, and learn how to think of a recursive breakdown(top-down approach). Then this question can be easily tackled. Note that direct recursive/backtracking would lead to Time limit getting exceeded.

Comment: EDIT : I added my solution above. Please, need some guidance.

Comment: @Dukeling - This is a question from the coding round of interview with a company.

Comment: @yasen - Posted my trial.

Comment: @Jim Mischel - Nope. Couldn't find the solution as this was a company interview coding question.

Comment: Could you post the kind of error you are facing? Wrong result? Takes too long to complete?

Comment: @phimuemue - Wrong result

Comment: @user2725880 Can you elaborate by showing some example input with actual and expected output?

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not solve your problem, but maybe it helps to take a look at so-called *simple transpositions* or *adjacent transpositions* of permutations (these correspond to swaps of neighboring characters) and how to express permutations as a sequence of such simple transpositions.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at this example:

```
aaaaaaaaab
abaaaaaaaa
```

Your solution: 8

```
aaaaaaaaab -> aaaaaaaaba -> aaaaaaabaa -> aaaaaabaaa -> aaaaabaaaa -> 
aaaabaaaaa -> aaabaaaaaa -> aabaaaaaaa -> abaaaaaaaa
```

Proper solution: 2

```
aaaaaaaaab -> baaaaaaaaa -> abaaaaaaaa
```

You should check if swapping in the other direction would give you better result.

But sometimes you will also ruin the previous part of the string. eg:

```
caaaaaaaab
cbaaaaaaaa

caaaaaaaab -> baaaaaaaac -> abaaaaaaac
```

You need another swap here to put back the 'c' to the first place.

The proper algorithm is probably even more complex, but you can see now what's wrong in your solution.

Answer (score 1):

[The A* algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_star) might work for this problem.

The initial node will be the original string.
The goal node will be the target string.
Each child of a node will be all possible transformations of that string.
The current cost `g(x)` is simply the number of transformations thus far.
The heuristic `h(x)` is half the number of characters in the wrong position.

Since `h(x)` is admissible (because a single transformation can't put more than 2 characters in their correct positions), the path to the target string will give the least number of transformations possible.

However, an elementary implementation will likely be too slow. Calculating all possible transformations of a string would be rather expensive.

Note that there's a lot of similarity between a node's siblings (its parent's children) and its children. So you may be able to just calculate all transformations of the original string and, from there, simply copy and recalculate data involving changed characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). Go over all swap possibilities while storing all the intermediate results along with the minimal number of steps that took you to get there. Actually, you are going to calculate the minimum number of steps for every possible target string that can be obtained by applying given rules for a number times. Once you calculate it all, you can print the minimum number of steps, which is needed to take you to the target string. Here's the sample code in JavaScript, and its usage for "aab" and "baa" examples:

```
function swap(str, i, j) {
   var s = str.split("");
   s[i] = str[j];
   s[j] = str[i];
   return s.join("");
}

function calcMinimumSteps(current, stepsCount)
{
   if (typeof(memory[current]) !== "undefined") {
      if (memory[current] > stepsCount) {
          memory[current] = stepsCount;
      } else if (memory[current] < stepsCount) {
          stepsCount = memory[current];
      }
   } else {
      memory[current] = stepsCount;
      calcMinimumSteps(swap(current, 0, current.length-1), stepsCount+1);
      for (var i = 0; i < current.length - 1; ++i) {
          calcMinimumSteps(swap(current, i, i + 1), stepsCount+1);
      }
   }
}

var memory = {};
calcMinimumSteps("aab", 0);
alert("Minimum steps count: " + memory["baa"]);
```

Comment: I think the algorithm is correct. But have you tried it with other inputs that `aab`? Because as far as I can judge, this algorithm basically computes *all* permutations -- which can be quite a lot, if the string is allowed to have length up to 2000, as mentioned in the question. To remedy this at least a bit, you could probably check if `stepsCount` is greater than `(length(current)*length(current)/2` (I think this should be a quite rough upper bound on the maximal number of swaps needed).

Comment: Didn't pay an attention to the 2000 characters upper limit.. My solution will not work probably, since it will require too much memory . The recursion can be rewritten using for() to eliminate call stack overflow, but this won't fix the whole memory issue still.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the ruby logic for this problem, copy this code in to rb file and execute.

```
str1 = "education" #Sample first string
str2 = "cnatdeiou" #Sample second string

moves_count = 0
no_swap = 0
count = str1.length - 1

def ends_swap(str1,str2)    
    str2 = swap_strings(str2,str2.length-1,0)
    return str2
end

def swap_strings(str2,cp,np)
    current_string = str2[cp]
    new_string = str2[np]
    str2[cp] = new_string
    str2[np] = current_string
    return str2
end

def consecutive_swap(str,current_position, target_position)
    counter=0
    diff = current_position > target_position ? -1 : 1
    while current_position!=target_position
        new_position = current_position + diff
        str = swap_strings(str,current_position,new_position)
        # p "-------"
        # p "CP: #{current_position}   NP: #{new_position} TP: #{target_position}  String: #{str}"
        current_position+=diff
        counter+=1
    end
    return counter,str
end

while(str1 != str2 && count!=0)
    counter = 1
    if str1[-1]==str2[0]
        # p "cross match"
        str2 = ends_swap(str1,str2)
    else
        # p "No match for #{str2}-- Count: #{count}, TC: #{str1[count]}, CP: #{str2.index(str1[count])}"
        str = str2[0..count]
        cp = str.rindex(str1[count])
        tp = count
        counter, str2 = consecutive_swap(str2,cp,tp)
        count-=1        
    end
    moves_count+=counter    
    # p "Step: #{moves_count}"
    # p str2
end

p "Total moves: #{moves_count}"
```

Please feel free to suggest any improvements in this code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Hope this will help you.

public class TwoStringIdentical {

```
static int lcs(String str1, String str2, int m, int n) {
    int L[][] = new int[m + 1][n + 1];
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i <= m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= n; j++) {
            if (i == 0 || j == 0)
                L[i][j] = 0;

            else if (str1.charAt(i - 1) == str2.charAt(j - 1))
                L[i][j] = L[i - 1][j - 1] + 1;

            else
                L[i][j] = Math.max(L[i - 1][j], L[i][j - 1]);
        }
    }

    return L[m][n];
}

static void printMinTransformation(String str1, String str2) {
    int m = str1.length();
    int n = str2.length();
    int len = lcs(str1, str2, m, n);
    System.out.println((m - len)+(n - len));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str1 = scan.nextLine();
    String str2 = scan.nextLine();
    printMinTransformation("asdfg", "sdfg");
}
```

}